# Map<String ,String[]> Converts to Map<String, Object[])

Tags: codenameone

I have a map

```
Map<String, String[]> newMetaData = new LinkedHashMap();
```

which I populate with data like this:

```
newMetaData.put( 
      ((String) elm.get("companyName")).trim(), 
      new String[]{
         this.storeFile( "logo", (String) elm.get("logoLink") ),
         this.storeFile( "profile", (String) elm.get("companyProfile") ),
         this.storeFile( "action", (String) elm.get("drash") ),
         (String) elm.get("fwtografies")
       }
 );
```

StoreFile is a function that returns string. I save this map to the storage as

```
Storage.getInstance().writeObject("MetaData", newMetaData);
```

Later on the code I retrive the above map as:

```
 Map<String, String[]> metaData = (Map)Storage.getInstance().readObject("MetaData");
```

But instead of getting a Map of <String, String[] & gt; I get Map of <String, Object[] >

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics in Java are syntax sugar. They are erased by the compiler and ignored by Codename One for the most part. This:

```
Map<String, String[]> newMetaData = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Is equivalent to this as far as the generated code is concerned:

```
Map newMetaData = new LinkedHashMap();
```

There are some caveats because the first version will also add casts when you use methods like set/put which could trigger a class cast exception in some cases. The thing is that this works in reverse as well so this should work just fine:

```
Map<String, String[]> metaData = (Map<String, String[]>)Storage.getInstance().readObject("MetaData");
```